# Windows cmd analog for bash $*

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

With bash I could make a file `run-with-environment`:

```
export THISENVVAR=3
$*
```

and run `run-with-environment echo 5` to have `echo 5` run with `THISENVVAR=3`.

On windows with `cmd.exe` I can make a batch file that sets

```
set THISENVVAR=3
```

Now what would be the analog of `$*`?

Comment: "to have echo 5 run with THISENVVAR=3" - What's the output in this case?

Comment: There was a very good answer posted here which seems to have been deleted...

Comment: Yeah I can see it below. It seems to have been deleted by the poster due to a comment from another user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with

```
@echo off    
    setlocal
    set "THISENVVAR=3"
    %*
```

Where `%*` is the full list of arguments given to the current batch file.